# Animate div when parent section is visible on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollview

I had this working but seem to have messed it up along the way.

I am using a scroll highjack that will bring the user to a new section/card each time they scroll.

It is adding a **visible** class each time the user scrolls to a new section/card.

I used this as the base https://codyhouse.co/gem/page-scroll-effects

```
<section class="cd-section visible">
  <div>
    <h2>Page Scroll Effects</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Then when the user scrolls to a new section it removes and adds the visible to the next section.

I am animating basic content at the moment like hero text etc for each section.

```
<section class="cd-section visible">
  <div class="home__content-slide-right">
    <h2>Page Scroll Effects</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am using the class name; **home__content-slide-right** here to animate this text using transform for now, which you can see below;

```
.home__content-slide-right {
   transform: translateX(-50px);
}
```

How I was doing it was buy just appending the **.visible** to the CSS which you can see below;

```
.visible .home__content-slide-right {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

This was working so when I scrolled to each page the animation played but now it seems to only work once when the whole page is loaded and that's it.

I have tried to remove somethings but have had no luck so far, just wondering here if anyone else had a reason for it not working.

------**Edit**------

I have added a few images below so you can see what my issue is.

This first image is with the section having the **.visible** class so the animation should be played.

[image]

Though as you can see when I leave the section and the .visible class is **removed** the css stays the same.

[image]

Comment: The way your last line of css is written, if any parent elements of .home__content-slide-right has the .visible class applied, this animation will happen. That may be the issue.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for the response but I had only started to adding in basic a few animations and used them once for each section. I have added images in case that helps people understand the issue I am having. I feel like you are on the right tracks though I just can't see it :(

Comment: So the css class is removed and the style still applies? The only reason that would happen is if you have a parent element of the section that has the "visible" class applied. Can you confirm that the body and all parents of that section do not have a visible class applied?

Comment: You are spot on my friend. I have the .visible class being applied to the body somehow :/. Thanks so much for the help, would have taken me a while to spot this one, hope you have a good week ahead of you :)

Comment: Very welcome. I just posted an answer with a bit more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the "visible" class being applied to a parent element of your target section.

Your css:

```
.visible .home__content-slide-right {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

is written so that any parent of that element with a .visible class will apply this css rule. If you want to ensure that this fires only when visible is added to the same section, re-write the css like this:

```
section.visible .home__content-slide-right {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Or make sure that no parent element has the visible class applied if it is unnecessary.